# Pandas slow on data frame replace

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have an Excel file (.xlsx) with about 800 rows and 128 columns with pretty dense data in the grid. There are about 9500 cells that I am trying to replace the cell values of using Pandas data frame:

```
xlsx = pandas.ExcelFile(filename)
frame = xlsx.parse(xlsx.sheet_names[0])
media_frame = frame[media_headers] # just get the cols that need replacing

from_filenames = get_from_filenames() # returns ~9500 filenames to replace in DF
to_filenames = get_to_filenames()

media_frame = media_frame.replace(from_filenames, to_filenames)
frame.update(media_frame)
frame.to_excel(filename)
```

The `replace()` takes 60 seconds. Any way to speed this up? This is not huge data or task, I was expecting pandas to move much faster. FYI I tried doing the same processing with same file in CSV, but the time savings was minimal (about 50 seconds on the `replace()`)

Comment: `from_filenames` and `to_filenames` is `lists` of `dicts`?

Comment: @jezrael no just flat lists of strings. Cell values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***strategy***
create `pd.Series` representing a `map` from filenames to filenames.
`stack` our dataframe, `map`, then `unstack`

***setup***

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from string import letters

media_frame = pd.DataFrame(
    pd.DataFrame(
        np.random.choice(list(letters), 9500 * 800 * 3) \
          .reshape(3, -1)).sum().values.reshape(9500, -1))

u = np.unique(media_frame.values)
from_filenames = pd.Series(u)
to_filenames = from_filenames.str[1:] + from_filenames.str[0]

m = pd.Series(to_filenames.values, from_filenames.values)
```

***solution***

```
media_frame.stack().map(m).unstack()
```

---

## timing

***5 x 5 dataframe***

[image]

***100 x 100***

[image]

***9500 x 800***

[image]

***9500 x 800***
`map` using `series` vs `dict`
`d = dict(zip(from_filenames, to_filenames))`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got the 60 second task to complete in 10 seconds by removing `replace()` altogether and using [set_value()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html) one element at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I found creating new col and dropping the existing column one is faster than waiting forever. ;)